# How to get key value from an array?

Tags: php, arrays

Here is the array:

```
$campaigns = 
Array (
[252] =>Array ( 
        [campaign_type_id] => 9 
        [company] => Array ( 
                    [company_name] => facebook 
                    [company_type] => 2 
                   )
        [campaign] => Array(
                    [pitch_id] => 27 
                    [pitch_campaign_title] => facebook mandate 
                        [pitch_campaign_description] => desc face 
                    [pitch_campaign_image] => db.png 
                   )
        [title] => Accelarator 
        [selection] => Array ( 
                    [0] => Array(
                             [ca_mandate_id] => 96 
                            [ca_id] => 252 
                            [ca_company_id] => 1 
                            [ca_updated] => 2015-12-31 12:37:50
                            )
                    ) 
        [campaign_created_by] => 3 
        [userinfo] => Array ( 
                    [0] => Array ( 
                            [user_id] => 3 
                            [user_first_name] => CoLabs 
                            [user_last_name] => Accelerator 
                            [user_img] => index2.jpg 
                            [user_designation_name] => Investor
                             [user_company_id] => 123
                              )
                     )
         )
   )
```

how can I get the value '252'? Its a dynamic value.
I want to get whatever value is stored in place of 252.

Please help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider `array_keys` http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php

Comment: Do this, `echo array_keys($campaigns)[0];`

Comment: Thank you all. I have solved it. array_keys is the solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the array_keys function: http://php.net/array_keys

> **array_keys** — Return all the keys or a subset of the keys of an array
>
> **Description** array array_keys ( array $array [, mixed $search_value = null [, bool $strict = false ]] )

For your code:

```
$keys = array_keys($campaigns);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try `array_keys`

```
array_keys() returns the keys, numeric and string, from the array.

$req_key = array_keys($campaigns);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `array_keys()` (as other suggested) and `key()` functions for getting this result.

**Difference is that:**

If you want to use `array_keys()` function it will returns you an `array` that consist of all `keys`.

If you want to use `key()` function it will returns you the first index of `array`. (you can get all `keys` by using loop);

**Example 1 (With array_keys):**

```
$arry = array(1,2,3);
echo "<pre>";
print_r(array_keys($arry));
```

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 2
)
```

**Example 2 (With key):**

```
$arry = array(1,2,3);
echo key($arry);
```

**Result:**

```
0 // index
```